# How do I run the following script in Raspberry pi 4 terminal as soon as it starts up?

Tags: raspberry-pi, object-detection, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

I am currently running the program via VNC and after startup I open the terminal and run the following code

```bash
cd home/documents/......
source venv/bin/activate
python new.py
```

as soon as i run this, the camera activates and the code to detect and announce what object is infront begins.
So what do I need to do to run the same on start up?
Also now every time I run the code, the whole raspberry just freezes and restarts, Is there any way to  fix this?

I tried using the `rc.local` method and it doesnt work.
Regarding the system freezing, I thought it was a space issue and tried clearing the wastebin which was kind of full but didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try following the steps mentioned here: https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/run-script-at-boot-raspberry-pi